# Computing FOLLOW sets for a LL(1) grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

I am trying to learn compiler design. But I get confused when I have to deal with computing the follow set specifically for the empty word.

Given the grammar:

```
S-> ABC
A-> Aa|b
B-> Bc|d
C-> Ce|f
```

I've come up with the following first and follow sets:

```
1 S->ABC   First(1)-{b}
2 A->bA'   First(2)-{b}
3 A'->aA'  First(3)-{a} 
4 A'->E    Follow(4)- ??
5 B->dB'   First(5)-{d}
6 B'->cB'  First(6)-{c}
7 B'->E    Follow(7)- ??
8 C->fC'   First(8)-{f}
9 C'->eC'  First(9)-{e}
10 C'->E   Follow(10)- ??
```

Please help me determine the follow sets I've indicated with `??`. Is there a formula I can use to determine the follow sets?

Comment: What is the definition of FOLLOW sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow set of something translates to asking: what symbol can come next in the string we are trying to read with the grammar rules the machine has?

Let's say we take a string `"abba"`. The input tape symbol will end the string with `$` as the delimiter. So we can say that `'a'`, `'b'`, `'b'`, `'a'` and `'$'` are the symbols that the read/write head of the parser will see while evaluating this string. I am taking the below production rules for this grammar.

```
S->AB
A->ab|a
B->baB|E
```

The string `"abba"` can be evaluated in the following manner:

```
S->AB
 ->abB
 ->abbaB
 ->abbaE
```

In the above case, `Follow(A) = {b,$}`.

`'b'` is part of the set because `B`'s production follows `A`'s production, `S->AB`, and whatever is the first letter that `B` produces will follow the last letter `A` produces.

Similarly, `$` is part of the set because of `B`'s epsilon production. 
When `B` is evaluated using rule `B->E`, then for `Follow(A)` there is no first letter produced by `B`.

In such a case where the `Follow(A)` is an epsilon production,

```
S->AE | using B->E
```

Then `Follow(A)` becomes `Follow(S)` which is `$`.

If you look at the string `"abba"`, once the last a is read the only symbol that can come after the string is `$`.

As a generalization, if `X->ABC` and `C->E`, then `Follow(B) = Follow(X)`.

In your question's example, evaluating `Follow(A')` results in only two possibilities where `A'` is on the RHS and can have a following symbol. Below are the two productions that can result:

```
A->bA'
A'->aA'
```

Unfortunately, out of the two one is `Follow(A') = Follow(A')` as per the rule I have mentioned in last line of the answer.

Hence we can only consider the other follow which is

```
Follow(A') = Follow(A)
```

i.e.

```
Follow(A) = First(B)
```

In a practical sense, if we have

```
S->ABC
```

and

```
A-> bA'
A'->aA'|E
```

Then whenever we have an A production, it will further lead to either `A -> baA'` or `A->b` (if we take `A'->E`).

In both cases the only thing that can follow `A'` is whatever is the first of `B`.

In a similar manner we can compute the same for `Follow(B')` and `Follow(C')`.

Comment: thanks Lavin, you have explained well. But can u tell me a perfect formula for this. So If I understand correctly then in above example.                  A'->E    Follow(4)- {d,$}              B'->E           Follow(7)- {f,$}  C'->E    Follow(10)- {$}

Comment: I have added an edit to the answer with points related to your question and I hope it helps.